# Make classmexer and ant working together

Tags: java, ant, profiling, memory-management

We're working on a java project and we use ant to build and run the program. Now we are doing some performance tests and we wanted to use [classmexer](http://www.javamex.com/classmexer/). The problem is that we can't get ant and classmexer work together.

Since it's necessary to pass to the jvm the argument

```
-javaagent:classmexer.jar
```

we have tried the following in our build.xml

```
<target name="run" description="Try running it." depends="all">
    <java jvmargs="-javaagent:classmexer.jar" jar="${OUT_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}.jar" failonerror="true" fork="true">
    </java>
</target>
```

but it doesn't work.
At runtime the program throws the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Agent not initted
          at com.javamex.classmexer.Agent.getInstrumentation(Agent.java:33)
          at com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(MemoryUtil.java:104)
          at com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(MemoryUtil.java:80)
          at output_archive.test.provaJDOM.main(provaJDOM.java:55)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
          at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
          at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
          at com.sun.star.lib.loader.Loader.main(Loader.java:141)
```

when `MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(Object)` is called

So it seems that this is not the correct way to pass the argument to the jvm, but we can't figure out what to do.

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably *are* passing the JVM arg successfully - you could try running ant with `-verbose` to confirm.  It seems likely that the issue though is with the the use of the `jar` attribute.

According to the Ant [`java` task docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) (*[see also](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html#-jar)*):

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user
>   classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

So, you'd have to have ensured that the classmexer.jar classes were included in the application jar for them to be found.

One other point: the `jvmargs` attribute is deprecated - you should use a nested `jvmarg` element instead.

An approach you might consider is to add your application jar to the classpath (along with classmexer.jar) and call the main class as specified in the jar manifest directly.  Something like this:

```
<java classname="...YourMainClass" failonerror="true" fork="true">
    <jvmarg value="-javaagent:classmexer.jar" />
    <classpath>
        <!-- other stuff here maybe -->
        <pathelement location="path_to_classmexer/classmexer.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${OUT_DIR}/${FILE_NAME}.jar" />
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clearly commented answer. However it does not work yet. Maybe something weird is happening with OpenOffice... The project is about writing an OpenOffice extension, so our code is loaded by OpenOffice itself, perhaps it ignores the arguments passed to the jvm and has (hopefully) another way to deal with this.
Anyway, thank you very much :-)